# GOINSECURE not working, it still use https, after go mod download,it report: parse https://code.demo.org/at?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags

Tags: go, https, dependencies, go-modules

I have a go mod`gitlab.org/at`, place at my private gitlab `code.demo.org/at`,which use `HTTP` protocol

My GOENV(`go env`):

```
GOVERSION="go1.19.13"
GOPRIVATE="code.demo.org"
GOINSECURE="code.demo.org"
```

And my `go.mod`:

```
module code.demo.org/demo

go 1.19

require (
    gitlab.org/at v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
)

replace gitlab.org/at => code.demo.org/at
```

I use `go mod tidy`,it error:

```
unrecognized import path "code.demo.org/at": parse https://code.demo.org/at?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags
```

That seems it use `HTTPS` to download this package, even has go env `GOINSECURE=code.demo.org`

I want use `HTTP` to download the package

Answer (score 0):

Reject the request to https://code.demo.org, then:

- in linux `iptables -A OUTPUT -d $IP -p tcp --dport 443 -j REJECT`
- in windows:
  `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Block_Outgoing_Connection" dir=out action=block remoteip=$IP protocol=TCP remoteport=443`